# PeopleSoft JSON Dynamic Property Data Type

Tags: .net, json, web-services, serialization, peoplesoft

I am a software engineer for a company that works with PeopleSoft HCM 9.1.  I write web services for our Sharepoint and .NET team to consume these RESTful web services.  The Content-Type I send them is application/json and the serialization that integration broker does is pretty great.  There is one issue that I've run into and our .NET engineer swears up and down that it's not legal; However, when I go to a JSON parser site  and check to see if it's valid, it says it is.  Here is the issue.  Data is coming across in JSON but there is a property whose data type for the first occurrence is an object.  The second row that comes in, changes it to a list/array.  I can't change this because it's part of the delivered serialization that Oracle PeopleSoft has implemented.  Here is the example -

```
{"C_DATA":
[{
         "HRS_PERSON_ID": 120483,
         "HRS_PROFILE_SEQ": 17,
         "HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID": 125075,
         "HRS_QSTN_ID": 1354,
         "HRS_JO_RQMT_SEQ": 1,
         "HRS_QSTN_ORDER_NBR": 4,
         "HRS_OPN_ENDED_QSTN": "Y",
         "HRS_DELETE_REQ": "",
         "HRS_REF_NUM_LONG": "",
         "HRS_RATING": "",
         "HRS_RANKING": 0,
         "HRS_ANSWER_ID": 0,
         "HRS_OPEN_ENDED_ANS": "",
         "C_ONLINE_SCREEN": "N",
         "DESCRLONG": "What is the phone number of your emergency contact?",
         "C_HRS_APP_QSTA":          {
            "HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID": 125075,
            "HRS_JO_RQMT_SEQ": 0,
            "HRS_QSTN_ID": 1354,
            "HRS_ANSWER_ID": 0,
            "CORRECT_ANSWER": "",
            "HRS_POINTS": 0,
            "DESCR254": "",
            "ORDER_SEQ": 0
         }
      },
            {
         "HRS_PERSON_ID": 120483,
         "HRS_PROFILE_SEQ": 17,
         "HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID": 125075,
         "HRS_QSTN_ID": 1355,
         "HRS_JO_RQMT_SEQ": 1,
         "HRS_QSTN_ORDER_NBR": 5,
         "HRS_OPN_ENDED_QSTN": "N",
         "HRS_DELETE_REQ": "",
         "HRS_REF_NUM_LONG": "",
         "HRS_RATING": "",
         "HRS_RANKING": 0,
         "HRS_ANSWER_ID": 0,
         "HRS_OPEN_ENDED_ANS": "",
         "C_ONLINE_SCREEN": "N",
         "DESCRLONG": "Have you ever been arrested?",
         "C_HRS_APP_QSTA":          [
                        {
               "HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID": 125075,
               "HRS_JO_RQMT_SEQ": 1,
               "HRS_QSTN_ID": 1355,
               "HRS_ANSWER_ID": 1000,
               "CORRECT_ANSWER": "N",
               "HRS_POINTS": 0,
               "DESCR254": "Yes",
               "ORDER_SEQ": 1
            },
                        {
               "HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID": 125075,
               "HRS_JO_RQMT_SEQ": 1,
               "HRS_QSTN_ID": 1355,
               "HRS_ANSWER_ID": 1001,
               "CORRECT_ANSWER": "Y",
               "HRS_POINTS": 0,
               "DESCR254": "No",
               "ORDER_SEQ": 2
            }
         ]
      }
]
}
```

Notice how the C_HRS_APP_QSTA property is first an object ( with {}), in the second run it's a list/array (it has the square brackets []).

First off, is this legal?  According to a JSON parser this is perfectly legal. (Checked it here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Second, is this best practice?  According to this .NET developer, he says that the web service should be like a contract so he knows what data types to expect and it shouldn't change on him like this.  Yes, I understand where he's coming from but is there a standardized industry practice?  If so, where is the documentation/proof?  I want a web site from some Computer Science page from a University or some legitimate document that says "this is best practice".

Now my last question, is it really hard for a developer to code it in a way where he can just check to see if it's a list or an object every time?  I don't think it is but this developer swears up and down that this is "too much code" or "too much work" to have to accommodate for this every time.

What say ye?  I hope this makes sense.  I tried to describe this as simple and explicit as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like I'm not the only person with this issues.  Here is somebody who posted something similar [link](http://scripting.com/stories/2010/12/18/questionForJsonGurus.html#thisCausesProblemsForPeopleInSomeLanguagesBecauseApparentlyItsHardForThemToDealWithAnObjectWithoutInAdvanceKnowingItsTypeSoTheySayTheSolutionIsSimpleAlwaysMakeItAListSimpleForThemBut)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in newer versions of PeopleTools 8.52+, Oracle finally fixed the serialization of JSON. So this was just an issue on older PeopleTools versions.

Answer (score 0):

We also face the same issues and personally I think Oracle screwed up on this. IMHO the .NET guy is right this isn't standard use.